# Making my simple program more efficient

Tags: python-3.x

I just learned Python two days ago so this is probably very bad. Since i want to get better at optimization and organization, is there anything specifically bad here or that i could improve. Wasted lines of code, things done in a more memory intensive way than it could be and so on. Thanks a lot for any input and I'm looking forward to learn much more.

```
from random import*
b = 10
a = randint(1,b)
point = 1
x = 1
while x < 2:
    print("Guess a number between 1 and ", b)
    svar = int (input())
    if svar == a:
            b+=5
            point= point+point
            a = randint (1,b)
            print("You have ", point, "points!")
    elif svar < a:
            print("Higher")
    else:
            print("Lower")
```

Comment: This is now on Code Review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97489/making-my-simple-program-more-efficient).